# discord.js client.user.setPresence() breaks bot

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

My bot currently runs fine. I decided to add a 'playing ' status to it. This is the relevant code:

```
// Import the discord.js modules required
const Discord = require('discord.js');

// Create an instance of a Discord client
const client = new Discord.Client();

// Load config properties from 'config.json'
const config = require("./config.json");
const contest = config.contest;

// Set bots status to playing 'contest' defined in 'config.json'
client.user.setPresence({
  game:{
    name:contest
  },
  status:'online'
});
```

In 'config.json':

```
{
  "contest": "Example Game"
}
```

When I add this, the bot no longer works, and appears offline. Any ideas?

EDIT:
Source of the information:

https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ClientUser?scrollTo=setPresence

In the example section:

```
// Set the client user's presence
client.user.setPresence({ game: { name: 'with discord.js' }, status: 'idle' })
  .then(console.log)
  .catch(console.error);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to read the config, instead of

```
const config = require(...)
```

You need

```
const fs = require("fs");
const config = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("config.json"));
const contest = config.contest;
```

Then

```
game:{
    name:contest
}
```

Comment: My config.json contains other properties which I reference through variables in exactly the same way and it works just fine. I don't think this is the issue.

EDIT: Phrasing

Comment: @XaviiteJV Hmm, are there any errors? What happens instead of setting it?

Comment: No errors, the app claims to have started, and since I removed health-checks as I want it running as a process, the deployment doesn't check if it continues running after the initial start, so any crashes aren't logged.

Comment: @XaviiteJV Is the bot online?

Comment: right now, yes, because I removed that code, but when I add the code it goes offline despite the deploy stage being successful

Comment: No, the example (copied and pasted char for char) has the same effect - successful deployment, but the bot is offline and inactive.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out - this needs to be placed inside an event, otherwise it's just floating code. For example, I placed this inside a 
client.on('ready) event.